# Reset AD passwords in batch without being an administrator?

Tags: passwords, active-directory, password-management, ldap

I have over a hundred test user accounts in AD that need to have their passwords changed periodically. These are just regular user accounts, but I'm not an administrator in AD. This keeps me from doing something like `net use test_account1 password /domain`. What I can do, is manually log into a server/workstation and `ctrl+alt+del` and change the password. As you might imagine, doing this for over 100 accounts is exhausting.

Is there a command that would allow me to batch reset these accounts, but do so as if I was a regular user that has the current password?

Edit: I'm the owner of these accounts, and am responsible for updating the passwords. I'm just not an AD admin.

Comment: Can you write a script to fail to authenticate over and over wrong until the account is locked and a password reset is required?

Comment: I could. But I'm not sure how that helps, though. Then I'd just have 100+ accounts that are locked that still need password changes.

Comment: Perhaps [ask the AD admin to delegate the right](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1464-how-to-delegate-password-reset-permissions-for-your-it-staff) (to your primary account) to change those users' passwords.

Comment: Interesting...I can ask, but I don't think they will. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use command line and runas? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427

Comment: I tried that this morning. I get prompted for the `runas` user, but then the prompt just goes away without letting me enter anything. /shrug. EDIT: Actually, it helps if I do this in cmd and not Cygwin. Sheesh! I still get an error though. But the screen flashes and I can't seem to grab it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, of course, a way of doing what you ask since it would be a massive security flaw.

You either have to be authenticated as the user you need to reset or be an administrator with password change permissions.

The only work around I can think of would be to rearrange your AD to put all of your accounts in their own OU and make you administrator of it.

Actually, another work around would be to make sure that all of the passwords are the same. Then you could easily script the changes from PowerShell.

UPDATE:

To use PowerShell to reset a users password, you need the [Set-ADAccountPassword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617261.aspx) cmdlet.

Here is an example taken from Technet:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity tmakovec -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "p@ssw0rd" -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "qwert@12345" -Force)
```

You can put a load of these into a loop or simply hard code them replacing the old and new passwords with variables to make it easy and consistent.

The only trouble is - I don't know if this needs admin level permissions and I don't have AD to hand to test I'm afraid. If not, I'll post something else to try.

Comment: Actually, all the passwords _are_ the same. :) So, how about that script? :) That's my problem. I just don't know what commands will do what I need, and I know virtually nothing about .Net and PowerShell.

Comment: Well, I'm not that much of an expert myself but I've updated the answer with some hints. Have fun learning some PowerShell!! It really is worth while.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the `Set-ADAccountPassword` needs to be installed and enabled somehow. I'll check the interwebs for how to do this, and check back if I'm able to get this to work.